# How to pass a model with extra unbound parameter from the view to the controller via ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know how to pass a model from the view to the controller via ajax using the 
"data: $(_form).serialize()" but how to also include an unbound value and pass both the model and this extra param all together ?

```
// Jquery
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: $(_form).serialize(),
});


// Controller
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult PostReservBooking(ReservFile model)
{
  .......
}

// Razor View
@model  ReservFile
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formRowDetails" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdNo)

            //Here are the components bound to model  
            ........  
            ........

            // This is the unbound component 
            @Html.TextBox("param1", new { @class = "form-control" })
         }
```

Comment: Refer the dupe, but what you should be doing is using a view model that contains the extra property and strongly bind to it (do not use data models in you view, especially when editing)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke That is exactly what I was looking for. ( I searched before posting but couldn't find it with that title.) If you post as an answer I can close the question.

Comment: I have already marked it as a dupe :) - answers can no longer be added